# 'NoneType' object is not iterable in a class

Tags: python

I'm writing a test script and met this problem:

```
ERROR - FAILED - ERROR Message:'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Code is here:

```
class tc_ID2****(****):
    def test_run(self):
        case_name = self.__class__.__name__
        logger.info("========== Begin of Running Test Case %s ==========" % self.__class__.__name__)
        try:
            the_list = self.list_objects("main-window")
            off_list = self.coveroff(the_list)
            if 'lblname' in off_list:
                self.assert_(True, case_name)
            else:
                raise FailException("Can't find the lable")
        except Exception, e:
            logger.error("FAILED - ERROR Message:" + str(e))
            self.assert_(False, case_name)
        finally:
            self.capture_image(case_name)
            self.restore_gui_environment()
            logger.info("========== End of Running Test Case: %s ==========" % case_name)

    def coveroff(self,the_list):
        off_list=[]
        for list_unit in the_list:
            if  isinstance(list_unit,list):
                off_list.extend(list_unit)
            else:
                off_list.append(list_unit)
        return  off_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

The list_object method will return a two-layer nested list.

```
def list_objects(self, window):
        logger.info("get objects list in window: %s" % window)
        all_objects_list = self.__parse_objects(ldtp.getobjectlist(self.get_locator(window)))
        logger.info("sorted all_objects_list: %s" % all_objects_list)

def __parse_objects(self, objects_list):
        logger.info("parse objects list")
        window_list = []
        tab_list = []
        button_list = []
        table_list = []
        text_list = []
        menu_list = []
        checkbox_list = []
        label_list = []
        others_list = []
        parsed_objects_list = [window_list, tab_list, button_list, table_list, text_list, menu_list, checkbox_list, label_list, others_list]
        for item in objects_list:
            if item.startswith("frm") or item.startswith("dlg"):
                window_list.append(item)
            elif item.startswith("ptab"):
                tab_list.append(item)
            elif item.startswith("btn"):
                button_list.append(item)
            elif item.startswith("ttbl") or item.startswith("tbl"):
                table_list.append(item)
            elif item.startswith("txt"):
                text_list.append(item)
            elif item.startswith("mnu"):
                menu_list.append(item)
            elif item.startswith("chk"):
                checkbox_list.append(item)
            elif item.startswith("lbl"):
                label_list.append(item)
            else:
                others_list.append(item)
        return parsed_objects_list
```

But I can't found things from a nested list.

So I made a method named coveroff to make the two-layer list become a simple list.

However this error just broke me down.

How can I debug this error?  Any idea is welcome!

Comment: You didn't post `list_objects` code but my guess is that this method is not returning anything

Comment: always add in question full error message (Traceback). There can be other usefull information - ie. which line makes problem.

Comment: @furas Thanks for you advise but I use nosetest to run the script and this is the only line I can post because others may break security agreement.

Comment: it seams some variable has value `None` and you try to use it as list so you try to do `None[idx]`. You can use `print()` to check values in variables and print some information to see which part will be executed before you get error. This way you can find line with problem and check all variables.

Comment: @furas Thanks ! I try to print those list and I fount lucasnadalutti is right! the list_objects didn't return anything.Thanks a lot for help, you save my day:)

Comment: @Ziyuan Ma glad you found the error. I posted it as an answer then so your question is not left open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, not having a `return` statement in your method is the same as returning `None`. So, your method is returning `None` when you expected it to return a list, thus the error.